# Building a SSRS 2008 off an EDM

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reporting, ado.net-entity-data-model

Can someone please outline the process of building a SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 report based on a ADO.Net Entity Framework Entity Data Model?
If you know of any example, please point me to it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to go through a web service. Just map your objects to your database, when creating a report choose "Object Data Source".

The only trick with Object Data Source, is if you need to access members of a related object you do it like this (for example if you want to print a first name of a person's parent.)

```
=Fields!Parent.Value.FirstName
```